# WhatsApp share not working properly while "&" is contain in link

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

**Sample Code:**

```
let sampleURL = "http://Hello/site/link?id=MTk=&fid=MTA="
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(sampleURL)"
if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
   if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
      if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
           UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL as URL)
      }
      else {
           // Open App Store.
      }
   }
}
```

added in .plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

Facing issue is while sharing link with **&** text not coming after **&**

For above url text is coming like **http://Hello/site/link?id=MTk=**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not want to escape `urlWhats` but `sampleURL` before putting it into `urlWhats`.

Comment: This probably won't help, but way back in the day an HTML **&** worked best as **&amp;** in character string literals? (EDIT: I think this has nothing to do with URL versus NSURL, it's simply HTML and maybe how a browser parses HTTP strings.)

Comment: The biggest misunderstanding about *URL encoding* is that it should be applied to URLs. That's incorrect. It should be applied to query parameters in URLs only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different parts of an URL have different encoding rules. `addingPercentEncoding` is very tricky to use correctly. As a rule, you should not try to encode your own URLs. Let the system do it for you with URLComponents:

```
//For the constant part of the link, it's fine to just use a string
var sample = URLComponents(string: "whatsapp://send")!

// Then add a query item
sample.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: "http://Hello/site/link?id=MTk=&fid=MTA=")]

// Extract the URL, which will have the correct encoding
print(sample.url!)
// whatsapp://send?text=http://Hello/site/link?id%3DMTk%3D%26fid%3DMTA%3D
```

Answer (score 0):

Try directly initialising to **URL** instead of **NSURL**

```
let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString)
```

and maybe use a completion handler to debug further

```
UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Not issue of URL instead of NSURL

Answer (score 0):

After some research and testing I found that while using **`.urlQueryAllowed`** in `AllowedCharacters` that will allow URL and does not change in URL that's why this issue occurs.

just use **`.init()`** like below on your text not include in that encoding `whatsapp://send?text=`
like below

```
let sampleURL = "http://Hello/site/link?id=MTk=&fid=MTA="
if let urlString = sampleURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .init()) {
    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(urlString)"
    if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlWhats) {
       if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL as URL)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main change in your code is that your try to escape the query parameter only, not the entire `whatsapp:` URL. That's good. The rest is nonsense. `.init()` will create an empty set of characters, i.e. no character will be replaced. You could as well remove the call to `addingPercentEncoding()` and would achieve the same result.

Comment: It's the other direction; it's encoding everything. The result of this is `whatsapp://send?text=%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%48%65%6C%6C%6F%2F%73%69%74%65%2F%6C%69%6E%6B%3F%69%64%3D%4D%54%6B%3D%26%66%69%64%3D%4D%54%41%3D`, which is legal, but excessive.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Empty character set for *withAllowedCharacters:* leads to excessive escaping.

Comment: @Codo `addingPercentEncoding()` this is not allowing me in `Swift5`

Comment: I not have been clear enough. You should revert it the to original parameters, i.e. `sampleURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)`